# Must declare scalar variable while displaying data in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

```
DateTime startSchedule = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime endSchedule = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
cn.Open();
string display = "select * from Issue where Date_Borrowed >= @startSchedule and Date_Borrowed < @endSchedule";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(display,cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startSchedule", startSchedule);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endSchedule", endSchedule);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(display, cn);
adapt.Fill(ds, "Issue");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Issue";
cn.Close();
```

I have two dateTimePickers and Im trying to display the data i have in my database that is within those two date.

Comment: What are the type of `Date_Borrowed` column?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not %100 sure but `AddWithValue` [*might*](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) be the reason in here. I would suggest to add your parameters with specifing their types.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startSchedule", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startSchedule;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endSchedule", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endSchedule;
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.